# Adding column containing foreign key to existing table in production in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, laravel-artisan, migrate

I have a table `participant` which has a `many-to-one` relationship with table `campaign`.  Now for some stupid reason I forgot to add a column `campaign_id`, which holds the foreign key to the row in table `campaign`. Now to fix this I could easily add the following line to the `create_participants_table` migration file and run the `php artisan migrate:fresh` command, which will drop all tables and recreate them with the right columns.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('campaign_id');
```

But the problem is that both tables are already in production and already contain data, so running `migrate:fresh` would not be optimal. So in that case I would create another migration file called `add_campaign_id_to_participants` like so:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('participants', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('campaign_id');
    });
}
```

The problem is that when running `php artisan migrate` I get an error that it `Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL`. Which seems fair  since the column isn't nullable and doesn't have a default value. But making the column nullable or set a default value doesn't seem desirable.

Now my `participants` table has a `one-to-one` relationship with table `visitors`, where every participant has a visitor, but not every visitor has a participant. Also the `visitors` table has a `many-to-one` relationship with table `campaign`. That means that in theory I could fill the just created `campaign_id` for a participant with something like:

`$participant->visitor->campaign->id`

Now my question is if this is somehow possible and if yes, how would I achieve this?

Comment: Try ` $table->unsignedBigInteger('campaign_id')->nullable();` or ` $table->unsignedBigInteger('campaign_id')->default(0);`. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-modifiers

Comment: I think you didnt understand the question @OlehTytarenko.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the following to the `add_campaign_id_to_participants` migration file.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('participants', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('campaign_id')->default(0);
    });
    $participants = Participant::all();
    foreach($participants as $participant)
    {
        $participant->campaign_id = $participant->visitor->campaign_id;
        $participant->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have just added an ordinary column, not a foreign key. There's nothing wrong with having a null value in a foreign key column; it just means there's no relationship.

Comment: Yes but in my case there needs to be a relationship. Every participant needs to have a linked campaign. But do you mean that instead of unsignedBigInteger I need to use foreign?

Comment: That is a business requirement, not a database requirement. And yes, you need to define the foreign key or it's just a column.

Comment: Is there a downside to have the foreign key not nullable?

Comment: No, just that it's not necessary. You define business rules in your code with e.g. request validations to ensure the relationship exists.